# Grouping Realm objects by distinct values of its fields

Tags: swift, realm

I'm looking for more elegant way of filtering and grouping realm objects by distinct values of its field.

I have realm objects of type Task with field of type Date. I want to group these objects by day.

```swift
class Task: Object {
   @objc dynamic var name: String 
   @objc dynamic var date: Date
//... other Realm Object implementation ...
}
```

I've created special struct to store and represent days and distinct them from each other.

```swift
struct Day: Hashable {
    var month: Int
    var year: Int
    var day: Int

    var hashValue: Int {
        return (year * 12 * 30) + (month * 30) + day
    }
}
```

And then added day of each task to the Set.

```swift
var days: Set<Day> = [] //moth, year, day

allRecords
    .forEach {
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .year, .day], from: $0.date)
        days.insert(Day(month: components.month!, year: components.year!, day: components.day!))
}
```

And then filtered all tasks by each day.

```swift
let history = days.map { day -> (String, Task) in
    let dayRecords = allRecords.filter { record in
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .year, .day], from: record.date)
        return components.year == day.year && components.month == day.month  && components.day == day.day
    }
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d"
    return (
        "\(dateFormatter.string(from: dayRecords.first?.date ?? Date()))",
        dayRecords)
    })
}
```

This code works and does what I want, but I'm sure there is a way of doing it more elegant and short.

My first thought: May be I should store date as Day class.
My second thought: there must be a way of queueing objects by it's inner object's fields values.

Thanks in advance!

P.S:
Possibly my question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728842/grouping-by-distinct-values) but with realm and swift.

Comment: When you say *group these objects by day*, can you provide an example of what that means; does group mean sort? Group them into a set? Group all mondays into an array? Sorted by?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, this is what you’re looking for:

```swift
let tasksByDate = Dictionary(grouping: tasks) {
    return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: $0.date)
}
```

This creates a dictionary which contains the tasks (values) grouped by date (keys).

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init

Comment: Thanks, this partially improves the algorithm. However I think this doesn't solve the whole problem. Do you know the complexity of this method? (Docs doesn't specify) Also may be there is a way to get it directly from Realm?